# Redirecting https to http as well as domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to do some redirects where https redirects to http as well as any instances where domain.com is typed in is redirected to www.domain.com.

A practical example would be where https://domain.com is redirected to http://www.domain.com - below is the regex code I used in the .htaccess file.  Would appreciate your help in clarifying.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, just need to tweak your rules a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on

# we handle to domain.com to www.domain.com first
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# then we redirect anything with HTTPS to just HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for though